# PHP Multiple Conditions in Select Option "Selected"

Tags: php

I have a drop-down list in a form, and I'm trying to make Texas selected when `prop_state` is TX AND `firmID` is not 1, and to select TX - MM Referral when `prop_state` is TX and `firmID` is 1. I've tried a couple methods and it always selects Texas. When `prop_state` is FL, it selects Florida fine. Just can't get it to select the third option when both conditions are met, and not sure where I've gone wrong.

```
<select name="conType" id="conType">
    <option value="FL" <?php if($row['prop_state']=="FL") echo "selected"; ?>>Florida</option>
    <option value="TX" <?php if($row['prop_state']=="TX" && $row['firmID']!="1") echo "selected"; ?>>Texas</option>
    <option value="TXMM" <?php if($row['prop_state']=="TX" && $row['firmID']=="1") echo "selected"; ?>>TX - MM Referral</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name="conType" id="conType">
    <option value="FL" <?php if($row['prop_state']=="FL"): echo "selected"; ?>>Florida</option>
    <option value="TX" <?php elseif($row['prop_state']=="TX" && $row['firmID']!="1"): echo "selected"; ?>>Texas</option>
    <option value="TXMM" <?php elseif($row['prop_state']=="TX" && $row['firmID']=="1"): echo "selected"; endif;?>>TX - MM Referral</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Throwing a syntax error: unexpected if (T_IF), expecting ':' on the second and third options

Comment: @mike437 try it again with the last one is else, I have updated the answer, check it

Comment: `elseif ` not else if , try it again

Comment: No errors, but not working. Same issue as before. Testing it where prop_state is TX and firmID is 1, and it's still selecting the second option instead of the third.

Comment: try with this 
$row['firmID']!=="1"
$row['firmID']==="1"

Comment: if not then you should debug 'firmID'  print it if it returns 1 or not

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in formatting.

Use `" selected"` instead of `"selected"`.(See Space before `selected`)

Following is corrected code:

```
<select name="conType" id="conType">
    <option value="FL" <?php if($row['prop_state']=="FL") echo " selected"; ?>>Florida</option>
    <option value="TX" <?php if($row['prop_state']=="TX" && $row['firmID']!="1") echo " selected"; ?>>Texas</option>
    <option value="TXMM" <?php if($row['prop_state']=="TX" && $row['firmID']=="1") echo " selected"; ?>>TX - MM Referral</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Can you share content of `$row`? Are you sure that `$row['firmID']` is storing a `string` value and not `int`?